# Need to know the binary lower bit change impact in circuit

Tags: driver, buffer

[image]

for example if i need 99 decimal number need on output, and ima giving binary digit of 01100011 in
Nexperia part and iam replacing that part with Texas part, what is the effect on the circuit can u please explain with example

For example if my output want to be 99(01100011) value, then i must provide following binary digit for the pins 1A0 0   2 pin 1A1   1   4 pin 1A2   1 6 pin 1A3 0   8 pin 2A0   1   17 pin 2A1  1   15 pin 2A2  0   13 pin 2A3  0   11 pin Whereas if i provide Texas part as drop in replacement for Nexperia part, the following will happen1A1   0   2 pin 1A2   1   4 pin 1A3   1   6 pin 1A4   0 8 pin 2A1 0   11 pin 2A2  0   13 pin 2A3  1   15 pin 2A4  1   17 pin, so my question is whether this will affect my design or not

Then why different manufacturer gives different naming for the pins, why the need?is that based on pin number only design will happen and not based on pin naming?

Comment: This question is unclear. The two circuits you show are the same because its the same '74' type part, so why show them? What is "lower bit change"? You don't show the external connections/circuit and then ask what the affect will be on the "circuit". The word "impact" can mean just about anything. Please be specific with what you want to know. For example, "I have a meter-long ribbon cable that I want to send parallel values at 500kHz, and each bit is terminated with 200 ohms. So if I change the part as described, will it affect the slew rate when going from a '1' to a '0'?".

Answer (score 0):

As you can easily see, the pinning is the same with both ICs:

```
pin IN  corresponding pin OUT
2       18
4       16
6       14
8       12
11      9
13      7
15      5
17      3
```

OE pins are also the same. 
The **naming** of the pins is different, but this has obviuosly no effect on functionality.
Generally, if two ICs of the 74xx series from whatever supplier have the same number (244 in this case) you can assume that they are 1:1 pin compatible.